# Using columns from another table in mysql if statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I wrote a trigger something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_after_itemPresent` AFTER INSERT ON `bus_repair`
FOR EACH ROW begin
    IF NEW.unit <> `item_present`.`unit` THEN
        update item_present 
        set unit = unit-new.unit 
        where item_present.item_group_id = new.item_group_id;
    END IF;
end
```

But when I insert new row in `bus_repair` table it gives an error that:

> unknown table item_present in field list

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: are you sure `unit-new` shouldn't be `unit_new`? Can you show the structure of the item_present table?

Comment: bro thats unit(minus)new.unit.....unit is from item_present table and new.unit is from bus_repair table....now i have checked the trigger without any if statement, it works fine. But when i included if statement it shows the error. i'm sure that the problem is in if part.

Answer (score 0):

Move your UPDATE item_preset statement above the IF and the IF inside the UPDATE or rephrase as a condition. You need to UPDATE or SELECT the table item_present first.